# Analyze a Crash Dump (.dmp) from .NET

Tags: c#, windbg, binaryfiles, crash-dumps

I need to read the binary file `CrashDump.dmp` from C#. If I use WinDbg I can read the file and see the content but I don't want to use the GUI because we want to automatically analyze several files.

I want to be able to do the same from C#. It would be good if there is some API for the case.

Comment: apart from the answer if you want to use pure c# and dont want to use any mdbg or whatever  you can refer to this hack i wrote some time back https://github.com/blabberer/chashdbg

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cdb` instead of WinDbg and run a WinDbg script. In this script, you can use extensions like SOS or [PyKd (Python)](https://pykd.codeplex.com/) to get the task done. Such a solution would not even require C# code. This works quite well for kernel dumps or dump files of native applications.

It's also possible to build a debugger in C# using the [CLR managed debugger engine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2282), which is also available as a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.MdbgEngine/). Note that this focuses on .NET applications. You'll probably not get as good results for native applications or kernel dumps.

I found the following tutorial: [Writing an automatic debugger in 15 minutes](https://tripleemcoder.com/2011/12/10/writing-an-automatic-debugger-in-15-minutes-yes-a-debugger/), which might be a good starting point for you.

Comment: FYI: See here for a potential problem analyzing memory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624824/reading-objects-from-memory-with-mdbgeng